# How to az group list using ubuntu bash foreach json array name value

Tags: json, shell, jq

azure cli `az group list` return data like

```json
[
  "demo3",
  "demo",
  "demo2",
  "NetworkWatcherRG"
]
```

I'd like to foreach it's value on ubuntu bash then printing below result

```
demo3
demo
demo2
NetworkWatcherRG
```

What I've tried :
I tried below script

```
jq -c '.[]' $(az group list) | while read i; do echo $i ;done
```

but get image's error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command expands to this (see it for yourself with `set -x`):

```
jq -c '.[]' '[' '"demo3",' '"demo",' '"demo2",' '"NetworkWatcherRG"' ']'
```

The command substitution is replaced with the command output, but jq doesn't expect a JSON body as a parameter – either files containing JSON, or a stream in standard input. Since all the parameters (`[`, `"demo3"` etc.) are *not* filenames, you see the errors you do.

You could have Bash make it look like it's a file with process substitution:

```sh
jq -c '.[]' <(az group list)
```

or, more portably, use pipes:

```sh
az group list | jq -c '.[]'
```

---

Notice that quoting wouldn't help here either: if you ran

```sh
jq -c '.[] "$(az group list)"
```

it would expand to

```sh
jq -c '.[]' '[
  "demo3",
  "demo",
  "demo2",
  "NetworkWatcherRG"
]'
```

and jq would try to open a file with the name

```
[
  "demo3",
  "demo",
  "demo2",
  "NetworkWatcherRG"
]
```

which does not exist.